# Query is working in MySQL 5.6 but not MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, settings

I have 2 applications in Google Apps Script. They both have the exact same coding and data in the database. One of them runs version 5.6 in MySQL (which is the one that's working). The other run runs off of version 5.7 in MySQL. The query is exactly the same for both Scripts but the one running version 5.6 is not filling the table with the rows all the way. Its acting as if there is a limit setting somewhere that needs to be changed. It will just stop and not calculate the total.

```
SELECT DISTINCT dp.id, dp.`driver_code`, CONCAT(tdr.first_name, ' ', tdr.last_name) AS driver_name,
      GROUP_CONCAT( 
        dp.ivh_invoicenumber, ':', dp.`as_code`, ':', DATE(sih." + SETTINGS.INV_PAY_ORDER + "), ':', 
        CONCAT(sih.shipper_city, ', ', sih.shipper_state), ':', 
        CONCAT(sih.consignee_city, ', ', sih.consignee_state), ':', 
        asl.`description`, ':', dp.pay, ':', dp.paid 
        ORDER BY sih." + SETTINGS.INV_PAY_ORDER + " SEPARATOR '|' 
      ) AS invoices 
    FROM DriverPay AS dp 
    JOIN `tptdrivr` as tdr 
    ON tdr.`driver_code` = dp.`driver_code` 
    JOIN `Salisbury_invoiceheader` AS sih 
    ON sih.`ivh_invoicenumber` = dp.`ivh_invoicenumber` 
    JOIN tptasssr AS asl 
    ON asl.`as_code` = dp.`as_code` 
    WHERE dp.paid < 2 " + pDates + "" + terminal + "
    GROUP BY dp.`driver_code`
    ORDER BY dp.`driver_code` ;
```

I have attached a snippet that shows what the outcome is for the script running MySQL 5.7.3. Is there a setting I need to change somewhere? Any advice would be greatly appreciated[image of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPlfQ.png)

Comment: please provide a [mre] and read up on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Check for [`group_concat_max_len`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) value. Increase it if its value is not big enough.

Comment: That worked! thank you!

Comment: There's no need to use `DISTINCT` when you use `GROUP BY`.